Permission Denied Error When Creating Files in NFS-Mounted Directory Despite Correct Group Permissions
I have an NFS share configured on HP 3PAR storage with the following details:
NFS Share Name: Thunder
The NFS share is successfully mounted on my Linux machine at /Thunder:
Mount Command: mount.nfs 192.168.x.x:/VFS_FPG/VFS/VFS/Thunder /Thunder
I also have a FreeIPA server where I created a group named thunder and added members test, test1, and test2 to this group. I then assigned the following permissions to the mounted
chown -R root:thunder /Thunder
chmod -R 775 /Thunder
However, when I switch to the user test and try to create a file or directory under
/Thunder, I get a "permission denied" error.
What I've Tried:
Verified that the user test is a member of the thunder group. Checked the ownership and permissions on /Thunder (shows as root:thunder with 775 permissions).
